# How to set to email from project.properties files

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I need to trigger two emails for my application, one to logged-in user and one to customer-care.
For the customer care, I am setting the email id in project.properties and then hitting the event class:

**deleteAccountSupportEvent.setAgentEmail(agentEmailAddress)**;

agentEmailAddress is picking email id from project.properties:
final String agentEmailAddress = getConfigurationService().getConfiguration().getString(DELETE_REQUEST_EMAIL_TO_AGENT);

I have set the email in Context class as well :
**setAgentEmail(((PHDeleteAccountEmailProcessModel) processModel).getAgentEmail());**

But instead of all this, mail is getting triggered to logged-in user.
Please help.

Comment: Does your event extend `AbstractCommerceUserEvent`? What are you setting as a customer to that event with `myEvent.setCustomer()` then? Maybe if you don't set it, logged user is set instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep it simple as follows:

```
final String agentEmailAddress = getConfigurationService().getConfiguration().getString(DELETE_REQUEST_EMAIL_TO_AGENT);

setAgentEmail(agentEmailAddress);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know context is used for mail body dynamic content. There might be logic where to email addresses are added.